# AlreadyBuiltException running Spring Boot application with spring security

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I am building secured Spring Boot application following the exact [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/).

This is my security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
            GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                    .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                    .contextSource().ldif("classpath:test-server.ldif");            
        }
    }   

}
```

However when I run the application within Spring Tool Suite, I got the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
```

If I comment out `@Configuration` before `AuthenticationConfiguration` class def, this error will go away. However I don't think the ldap auth is configured if the `@Configuration` annotation is removed.

Why does it say the object was already built? What "object" is it referring to? Below is dependencies in my pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>apacheds-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Add `@Autowired` to the `init` method..

Comment: @AliDehghani Tried that, still the same error.

Comment: Add your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`..

Comment: @AliDehghani Pom added. I noticed there is another error before this one `ClassNotFoundException` for `Directory Server`. Not sure if the two are related.

Comment: Change `apacheds-all` version number from `2.0.0-M20` to `1.5.5`.

Comment: @AliDehghani Changed to 1.5.5 but getting error `SLF4J: The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6]`

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot?

Comment: @AliDehghani 1.3.3.RELEASE

Comment: It works if I switch to `apache-server-jndi 1.5.5` according to this [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/). I do not understand why though

Comment: Spring Security only supports ApacheDS 1.5.5 due to breaking API changes in 2.0 and more recent 1.5.x releases

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Can you make one of your comments the answer, so I can close the post?

Comment: @ddd I've added an answer based on my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use ApacheDS 2.0, but Spring Security only supports 1.5.5 due to breaking API changes in 2.0 and more recent 1.5.x releases. Updating your pom to use 1.5.5 should fix the problem.